# Why ServiceStack.Redis does not use SET Timeout for acquiring lock?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

if you look at the code of [RedisLock.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisLock.cs) class you can see that it is reading the lock value to validate timeout itself outside Redis and it is also using Watch and Unwatch to overwrite timeout value if nobody touched it.

In another words, what are the exact points of using watch and unwatch and commit while we can use Redis internal set timeouts which are even more reliable?

```
ExecUtils.RetryUntilTrue(() =>{
    //This pattern is taken from the redis command for SETNX http://redis.io/commands/setnx

    //Calculate a unix time for when the lock should expire
    var realSpan = timeOut ?? new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0); //if nothing is passed in the timeout hold for a year
    var expireTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(realSpan);
    var lockString = (expireTime.ToUnixTimeMs() + 1).ToString();

    //Try to set the lock, if it does not exist this will succeed and the lock is obtained
    var nx = redisClient.SetValueIfNotExists(key, lockString);
    if (nx)
        return true;

    //If we've gotten here then a key for the lock is present. This could be because the lock is
    //correctly acquired or it could be because a client that had acquired the lock crashed (or didn't release it properly).
    //Therefore we need to get the value of the lock to see when it should expire

    redisClient.Watch(key);
    var lockExpireString = redisClient.Get<string>(key);
    if (!long.TryParse(lockExpireString, out var lockExpireTime))
    {
        redisClient.UnWatch();  // since the client is scoped externally
        return false;
    }

    //If the expire time is greater than the current time then we can't let the lock go yet
    if (lockExpireTime > DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMs())
    {
        redisClient.UnWatch();  // since the client is scoped externally
        return false;
    }

    //If the expire time is less than the current time then it wasn't released properly and we can attempt to 
    //acquire the lock. The above call to Watch(_lockKey) enrolled the key in monitoring, so if it changes
    //before we call Commit() below, the Commit will fail and return false, which means that another thread 
    //was able to acquire the lock before we finished processing.
    using (var trans = redisClient.CreateTransaction()) // we started the "Watch" above; this tx will succeed if the value has not moved 
    {
        trans.QueueCommand(r => r.Set(key, lockString));
        return trans.Commit(); //returns false if Transaction failed
    }
},timeOut);
```

Because StackExchange.Redis Library equivalent only use string.set capabilities. despite the fact that that ServiceStackRedis locking mechanism is more advanced and will wait and retry until get a lock but still not using timeouts of REDIS SET command itself is not justified.

```
public bool LockTake(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, TimeSpan expiry, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)            {
    if (value.IsNull) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    return StringSet(key, value, expiry, When.NotExists, flags);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code: it uses the time as the value, and checks it; if you don't have a separate payload to store, that's valid - although it does seem a shame not to use the server's inbuilt timeout functionality (not least so that the client's `DateTime.UtcNow` doesn't matter)